# Create New Column using selected substring(s) from multi-value field

Tags: openrefine

I've got a pretty large (800 rows) OpenRefine dataset. One cell contains multiple values that vary, but with a consistent structure (see example below) with data split by commas similar to a json array. I want to create a new multi-value column that just contains the elements from a specific category such as Creator or Subject. In the example below, I'd like to create a new column called Item Creator that would include only Dana M. Ashley and John Smith, the two that are found in the text. So far I've tried the expression `forEach(value.split(","), v, v.contains("Creator:"))` and I get an array that recognizes the segments that include Creator, but I don't yet understand how to extract that string text into the new column. Help would be much appreciated.

`Publisher: American Federation of Teachers, Creator:  Dana M. Ashley, Creator:  John Smith, Subject:     Prosocial behavior, Subject: Program development, Subject: Behavior problems, Subject: Classroom techniques, Subject: Student behavior, Subject: School culture, Subject: Educational environment, Subject: Positive Behavior Supports, Resource Type: Text, Language: English, Audience: Educator, Format: pdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put this value in a new column use the dropdown menu in your current column (that contains the combined data) and choose "Edit Column -> Add column based on this column"

If you replace the 'forEach' expression with a 'filter' expression in the GREL formula you've got here and you get the list of creators (in an array). To store these in a cell, you can join the array into a string:

```
filter(value.split(","), v, v.contains("Creator:")).join("|")
```

This should get you the new column with a list of creators - it will need some more tidying up to remove the "Creator: " bit to get just a list of names

Comment: Thanks Owen. I wasn't clear - I understand the process of creating a new column, but where I'm stumped is taking the array items that are true from the split and turning them into text in the associated new column. Here's and example what I get displayed in preview when I use the GREL formula I listed. - `[ false, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ]`

Comment: If you use 'filter' in place of 'forEach' in the GREL you'll get the values instead of true/false

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks much.